# Possible to write this typescript without using the exports command

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, visual-studio-2015, typescript1.8

Learning TypeScript and have a simple Angular service:

```
interface IBaConfigFactory {
    dateTimeNow: Date; 
}

export class BaConfigFactory implements IBaConfigFactory {
    dateTimeNow: Date;

    constructor() { 
        this.dateTimeNow = new Date();
    }
}

angular
    .module("blogApp")
    .service("BaConfigFactory", BaConfigFactory);
```

But the brower complains:

> baConfigService.ts:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined(anonymous function) @ baConfigService.ts:6 app.ts:48

From what I'm learning, I would then need something like Webpack or CommonJS to get the browser to understand exports. Is it possible to rewrite this so that I do not wind up with an export command? Focusing on learning one thing at a time.

Comment: I don't know if there's a way to do this without using `export`. It is easy to include a module system with VS2015. The options are in the Project properties under TypeScript Build > Module system.

Comment: I had to include require.js in my project. Set my tsconfig.json to target es6 and use AMD as a module build system. That did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need export if you don't load your file using a modules system, and if you don't place your code in a module/namepsace.

For example, this should work fine:

```
class MyClass {
    private x: number;

    constructor(x: number) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    getX(): number {
        return this.x;
    }

    doit(y: number): number {
        return this.x * y;
    }
}

function echo(value: any): any {
    return value;
}
```

(sample.ts)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="example.js"></script>
        <script>
            var a1 = new MyClass(10),
                a2 = new MyClass(43);

            console.log(echo("hey there!"));
            console.log(a1.doit(a2.getX()));
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

However, using `export` should be just fine because it should not appear in the compiled js (just be sure not to use `-m` or `--module` in the [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)).

For example, this:

```
module MyModule {
    export class MyClass {
        private x: number;

        constructor(x: number) {
            this.x = x;
        }

        getX(): number {
            return this.x;
        }

        doit(y: number): number {
            return this.x * y;
        }
    }

    export function echo(value: any): any {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Gets compiled into this:

```
var MyModule;
(function (MyModule) {
    var MyClass = (function () {
        function MyClass(x) {
            this.x = x;
        }
        MyClass.prototype.getX = function () {
            return this.x;
        };
        MyClass.prototype.doit = function (y) {
            return this.x * y;
        };
        return MyClass;
    }());
    MyModule.MyClass = MyClass;
    function echo(value) {
        return value;
    }
    MyModule.echo = echo;
})(MyModule || (MyModule = {}));
```

([Code in Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=module%20MyModule%20%7B%0D%0A%09export%20class%20MyClass%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09private%20x%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%09%09constructor(x%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09this.x%20%3D%20x%3B%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%09getX()%3A%20number%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09return%20this.x%3B%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%09doit(y%3A%20number)%3A%20number%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09return%20this.x%20*%20y%3B%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%09export%20function%20echo(value%3A%20any)%3A%20any%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20value%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D))

And you'll notice that there are not `export` in the compiled js.
Then you simply:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="example.js"></script>
        <script>
            var a1 = new MyModule.MyClass(10),
                a2 = new MyModule.MyClass(43);

            console.log(MyModule.echo("hey there!"));
            console.log(a1.doit(a2.getX()));
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```